# How to add a value in an Array?

Tags: javascript

Let's imagine I have this :

```js
var fruits = [{ "Banana" : "yellow", "lemon" : "yellow"}, {"Orange" : "orange", "Mango" : "orange"}, {"Apple" : "red", "strawberry" : "red"}];

fruits.push({"Kiwi" : "green", "Green Apple" : "green", "watermelon" : "green" });

console.log(fruits);
```

Now I have an Array "fruits", with objects inside, and I'm using "push()" method to add new objects.

If I would like to add a new yellow fruit, like "Jamaican Banana : yellow" inside the yellow things object, how could I do that ?

Comment: you have wrong syntax of objects

Comment: Your example isn’t syntactically valid. If you meant `{"Banana": "yellow", "lemon": "yellow"}`… why store them like that? It’s the least useful structure. `{"yellow": ["Banana", "lemon"], "orange": …}"` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Have you tried to run this ?

Comment: You should use a hash

Comment: Actually, it's just an random exemple. In my project I'm using a firebase ref to fill up the array using a foreach. Then I have my Array, fill up with objects inside that I transfer to the scope.

And I would like to know if it exist a simple way to add something in these objects. Because the problem with the "push" method is, each push create a new object. Wich is an action I want, but I also would like to add something more in each steps of my loop, am I enough clear ?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do won't work very well. Try something like this:

```js
var fruits = {
  yellow: ["fruit1", "2", "3"],
  orange: ["4","5","6"]
};

// later
console.log(fruits);
fruits.yellow.push("another fruit");
console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the keys, if necessary and the string values, but not the wole part with colon inside: [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var fruits = [{ Banana: "yellow", lemon: "yellow" }, { Orange: "orange", Mango: "orange" }, { Apple: "red", strawberry: "red" }];

fruits.push({ Kiwi: "green", "Green Apple": "green", watermelon: "green"});

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic property accesses (bracket notation), and don't forget the quotes that go between property names and `:` in your other fruit objects:

```js
var fruits = [{
  "Banana": "yellow",
  "Lemon": "yellow"
}, {
  "Orange": "orange",
  "Mango": "orange"
}, {
  "Apple": "red",
  "Strawberry": "red"
}]

fruits.push({
  "Kiwi": "green",
  "Green Apple": "green",
  "Watermelon": "green"
})

fruits[0]["Jamaican Banana"] = "yellow"

console.log(fruits)
```

However, I would suggest (like [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) and [Mehul Mohan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42851967/7256039) have already) using arrays within a top-level `fruits` object instead (in other words, sorting your data by color):

```js
var fruits = {
  "yellow": ["Banana", "Lemon"],
  "orange": ["Orange", "Mango"],
  "red": ["Apple", "Strawberry"]
}

fruits["green"] = ["Kiwi", "Green Apple", "Watermelon"]

fruits["yellow"].push("Jamaican Banana")

console.log(fruits)
```

Comment: Oh that's seems to fit to my needs ! How would you do the same in a same Array size loop ? Let's imagine we have "fruits[iteration][fruit] = color", "iteration", "fruit" and "color" as variables.

Comment: Just like that: `for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) { fruits[i]["Example Fruit"] = "example-color" }`. However, this will mess up the sorting of your data which is why the alternative data structure I suggested is more desirable.

Comment: Actually, it's just an random exemple. In my project I'm using a firebase ref to fill up the array using a foreach. Then I have my Array, fill up with objects inside that I transfer to the scope. And I would like to know if it exist a simple way to add something in these objects. Because the problem with the "push" method is, each push create a new object. Wich is an action I want, but I also would like to add something more in each steps of my loop, am I enough clear ?